# I am trying to update my site to 8.6.3 and I receive the following message

Tags: 8, updating

When I try to update Drupal to **8.6.3** i receive the message

> CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: SYNC
>   The directory drupal-8/sites/default/config_acq does not exist.

I don't know what to do. Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Can you add more details to the question - were you aware of that directory? If you were, was it deleted in the update process? If not can you try creating one at the location?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `settings.php` file:

```
$config_directories = array(
CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY => 'sites/default/files',
);
```

For more information take a look to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/installing-drupal/2016-08-25/configuration-directory-sync-error)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to resolve your concerns

1. Either create the folder at specified location
2. Or change the setting into settings.php file. Below is the code

   $config_directories['sync'] = 'Path of sync directory';